# No module named 'conda' when trying to install graphviz

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, graphviz, miniconda

I am using spyder 5.4.0 with python 3.9.14 64-bit and miniconda 3.

While executing

```
conda create -n spyder-env -y
conda activate spyder-env
conda install spyder-kernels python-graphviz -y
```

in the terminal I get the following error

```
Sohams-MacBook-Pro:miniconda3 amaterasu$ conda create -n spyder-env -y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amaterasu/opt/miniconda3/bin/conda", line 12, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
Sohams-MacBook-Pro:miniconda3 amaterasu$ conda activate spyder-env
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amaterasu/opt/miniconda3/bin/conda", line 12, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
Sohams-MacBook-Pro:miniconda3 amaterasu$ conda install spyder-kernels python-graphviz -y
```

Comment: Does *any* conda command work properly (e.g. `conda info`)? How did you install miniconda, Python and Spyder?

Comment: I think this means your Miniconda installation is broken and now you have to reinstall it. I mean, I don't see any other way you can move forward because conda itself is not working.